# Attempting to save vector<int> in bin file and reading it gave random data

Tags: c++, vector, fstream

I wrote two functions to save and read data in a bin file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// save data in file with name p_file
template <typename T>
void save(string p_file, T data) {
    ofstream output(p_file, ios::binary | ios::out);
    output.write((char*) &data, sizeof(data));
    output.close();
}

// read and return data in file with name p_file
template <typename T>
T read(string p_file) {
    ifstream input(p_file, ios::binary | ios::in);
    T data;
    input.seekg(0, input.end);
    int length = input.tellg();
    input.seekg(0, input.beg);
    input.read((char*) &data, length);
    input.close();
    return data;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> vint;
    vint.push_back(1);
    save< vector<int> >("test.bin", vint);
    vector<int> load_vint = read< vector<int> >("test.bin");
    cout << vint[0] << endl;
    cout << load_vint[0] << endl;
    cout << "done" << endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
1
1
done
```

actual output:

```
1
1990048
done
```

Things got even worse when I put most of the code in `main` into `test` and didn't change anything in `save` and `read`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// save data in file with name p_file
template <typename T>
void save(string p_file, T data) {
    ofstream output(p_file, ios::binary | ios::out);
    output.write((char*) &data, sizeof(data));
    output.close();
}

// read and return data in file with name p_file
template <typename T>
T read(string p_file) {
    ifstream input(p_file, ios::binary | ios::in);
    T data;
    input.seekg(0, input.end);
    int length = input.tellg();
    input.seekg(0, input.beg);
    input.read((char*) &data, length);
    input.close();
    return data;
}

// exact same code, just in a function
void testing() {
    vector<int> vint;
    vint.push_back(1);
    save< vector<int> >("test.bin", vint);
    vector<int> load_vint = read< vector<int> >("test.bin");
    cout << vint[0] << endl;
    cout << load_vint[0] << endl;
}

int main() {
    testing();
    cout << "done" << endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
1
1
done
```

actual output:

```
1
1924512
```

What is going on and how do I fix this error?

Comment: The save routine literally writes the `vector`, which is typically implemented as a trio of pointers, to the file. That means the file contains three addresses that probably will not be valid when you read the file back in. You need to serialize the data you write if it is too complex for a simple function like `write`.

Comment: Like @user4581301 pointed out, `vector` doesn't really store the data in it, instead it only contains a few pointer to the data. As an alternative, you can use `std::array`, which does store data directly.

Comment: Check my updated answer. The solution is there and it works as you'd expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the address of the vector object to the `save` function (which lives on the stack) and not the underlying dynamic array (lives on the heap memory) which holds the `int`s. Also have a look at how std::vector works: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/an-introduction-to-stdvector/

**Here is my full solution with lots of refactoring and cleanup:**

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>


// save data in file with name p_file
void save( const std::string& p_file, const std::vector<int>& data )
{
    std::ofstream output( p_file, std::ofstream::binary );

    if ( !output.is_open( ) )
    {
        throw std::ios_base::failure( "Error while opening the file " + p_file );
    }

    for ( auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it )
    {
        output.write( reinterpret_cast< const char* >( &(*it) ), sizeof( int ) );
    }

    /*
    if ( !data.empty() )                 // Or use this instead of the for loop
    {
        size_t numOfBytes { data.size( ) * sizeof( int ) };
        output.write( reinterpret_cast< const char* >( &(data[0]) ), numOfBytes );
    }
    */

    output.close();
}

// read and return data in file with name p_file
std::vector<int> read( const std::string& p_file )
{
    std::ifstream input( p_file, std::ifstream::binary );

    if ( !input.is_open( ) )
    {
        throw std::ios_base::failure( "Error while opening the file " + p_file );
    }

    input.seekg( 0, input.end );
    size_t length = input.tellg();
    input.seekg( 0, input.beg );

    size_t numOfIntsInFile { length / sizeof( int ) };

    std::vector<int> data( numOfIntsInFile );

    for ( auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it )
    {
        input.read( reinterpret_cast< char* >( &(*it) ), sizeof( int ) );
    }

    /*
    if ( !data.empty() )                  // Or use this instead of the for loop
    {
        input.read( reinterpret_cast< char* >( &(data[0]) ), length );
    }
    */

    input.close();

    return data;
}

// exact same code, just in a function
void test()
{
    std::vector<int> vint;
    vint.push_back( 1 );
    vint.push_back( 2235 );
    vint.push_back( 3 ); // push back as many ints as you want, it won't break.

    std::vector<int> load_vint;

    try
    {
        save( "test.bin", vint );
        load_vint = read( "test.bin" );
    }
    catch ( const std::ios_base::failure& e )
    {
        std::cerr << "Caught an std::ios_base::failure.\n"
                  << e.what() << '\n'
                  << "Error code: " << e.code() << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "Printing the elements of vint: " << '\n';

    for ( const auto& element : vint )
    {
        std::cout << element << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "Printing the elements of load_vint: " << '\n';

    for ( const auto& element : load_vint )
    {
        std::cout << element << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    test();
    std::cout << "\nDone." << std::endl;
}
```

*Summary of the changes:*

1. I removed the templates since they were annoying me! You can add them to my code if you really need template functions and then use them.
2. Use **lvalue references** (like `const std::vector<int>&`) where possible to avoid unnecessary copies.
3. Use **C++ casts** (like `reinterpret_cast`) instead of C-style casts as much as possible.
4. Avoid polluting the whole source file by writing `using namespace std;` at the top. Use it in limited scopes.
5. Use `std::ofstream::binary` or `std::ifstream::binary` instead of `std::ios::binary` where dealing with `fstream` objects.
6. Also added exception handling mechanisms in case a file can not be opened.

Extra note: Cleaning the code and making it a bit more readable ensures that other people can easily read and understand your problem.

Comment: Fun fact: C++ can (but rarely is) be implemented without stacks and heaps.

Comment: @user4581301 Isn't it designed for Turing machines? How does it work without a stack?

Comment: I've never seen C++ implemented without a stack in the wild, but academics... They can get a little weird from time to time. Anyway, C++'s abstract model is so abstract that it just outlines the requirements for Automatic Memory and leaves how you do it up to you. If some wizard can figure out how to use unicorn horns or Care Bear stuffing to meet all of the requirements, more power to them.